# How does mdk3 work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Can anyone explain to me how does mdk3 work?

I just read mdk3 works by disconnecting network traffic near users who use it.

Does mdk3 transmit on some particular frequency?

Answer (score 0):

#### How does mdk3 work?

`mdk3` works by exploiting weaknesses in the IEEE 802.11 protocol.

It has different command line options ("test modes") for selecting particular exploits.

See below for a summary of the test modes. There is more complete documentation at [MDK3 Documentation](https://svn.mdk3.aircrack-ng.org/mdk3/docs/Documentation_incomplete.html)

---

#### WiFi Stress testing using MDK3, Beacon Flooding & Deauthentication Attack.

> Syntax : `mdk3 <interface> <testmode> <test-options>`
>
> `Mdk3 –help <test mode>` : for test options
>
> TEST MODES:
>
> - `b`   - Beacon Flood Mode
>
>   Sends beacon frames to show fake APs at clients. This can sometimes
>     crash network scanners and even drivers!
> - `a`   - Authentication DoS mode
>
>   Sends authentication frames to all APs found in range. Too much
>     clients freeze or reset some APs.
> - `p`   - Basic probing and ESSID Bruteforce mode
>
>   Probes AP and check for answer, useful for checking if SSID has been
>     correctly decloaked or if AP is in your adaptors sending range SSID
>     Brute-forcing is also possible with this test mode.
> - `d`   - Deauthentication / Disassociation Amok Mode
>
>   Kicks everybody found from AP
> - `m`   - Michael shutdown exploitation (TKIP)
>
>   Cancels all traffic continuously
> - `x`   - 802.1X tests
> - `w`   - WIDS/WIPS Confusion
>
>   Confuse/Abuse Intrusion Detection and Prevention Systems
> - `f`   - MAC filter bruteforce mode
>
>   This test uses a list of known client MAC Adresses and tries to
>     authenticate them to the given AP while dynamically changing its
>     response timeout for best performance. It currently works only on APs
>     who deny an open authentication request properly
> - `g`   - WPA Downgrade test
>
>   Deauthenticates Stations and APs sending WPA encrypted packets. With
>     this test you can check if the sysadmin will try setting his network
>     to WEP or disable encryption.

Source [WiFi Stress testing using MDK3, Beacon Flooding & Deauthentication Attack](http://kalilinuxtutorials.com/mdk3/)